# Disabling the Consul HTTP endpoints

Tags: acl, consul

We have enabled ACL's and TLS for Consul cluster in our environment. We have disabled the UI as well. But when I use the URL: http://<consul_agent>:8500/v1/coordinate/datacenters. How can disable the URL's as this?

I tested with adding the following to the consulConfig.json:

```
"ports":{
  "http": -1
}
```

this did not solve the problem.

Apart from the suggestion provided to use `"http_config": { "block_endpoints":` I am trying to use the ACL Policy if that can solve.

1. I enabled the ACL's first
2. I created a policy using the command: `consul acl policy create -name "urlblock" -description "Url Block Policy" -rules @service_block.hcl -token <tokenvalue>`
   contents of the service_block.hcl: `service_prefix "/v1/status/leader" { policy = "deny" }`
3. I created a `agent token` for this using the command: `consul acl token create -description "Block Policy Token" -policy-name "urlblock" -token <tokenvalue>`
4. I copied the `agent token` from the output of the above command and pasted that in the consul_config.json file in the `acl -> tokens` section as `"tokens": { "agent": "<agenttokenvalue>"}`
5. I restarted the consul agents (did the same in the consul client also).

Still I am able to access the endpoint `/v1/status/leader`. Any ideas as what is wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

That configuration should properly disable the HTTP server. I was able to validate this works using the following config with Consul 1.9.5.

### Disabling Consul's HTTP server

Create `config.json` in the agent's configuration directory which completely disables the HTTP API port.

#### config.json

```json
{
    "ports": {
        "http": -1
    }
}
```

#### Start the Consul agent

```sh
$ consul agent -dev -config-file=config.json
==> Starting Consul agent...
           Version: '1.9.5'
           Node ID: 'ed7f0050-8191-999c-a53f-9ac48fd03f7e'
         Node name: 'b1000.local'
        Datacenter: 'dc1' (Segment: '<all>')
            Server: true (Bootstrap: false)
       Client Addr: [127.0.0.1] (HTTP: -1, HTTPS: -1, gRPC: 8502, DNS: 8600)
      Cluster Addr: 127.0.0.1 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
           Encrypt: Gossip: false, TLS-Outgoing: false, TLS-Incoming: false, Auto-Encrypt-TLS: false

==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:
...
```

Note the HTTP port is set to "-1" on the Client Addr line. The port is now inaccessible.

#### Test connectivity to HTTP API

```sh
$ curl localhost:8500
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8500: Connection refused
```

### Blocking access to specific API endpoints

Alternatively you can block access to specific API endpoints, without completely disabling the HTTP API, by using the [`http_config.block_endpoints`](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options#block_endpoints) configuration option.

For example:

#### Create a config named block-endpoints.json

```json
{
  "http_config": {
    "block_endpoints": [
      "/v1/catalog/datacenters",
      "/v1/coordinate/datacenters",
      "/v1/status/leader",
      "/v1/status/peers"
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Start Consul with this config

```sh
consul agent -dev -config-file=block-endpoints.json
==> Starting Consul agent...
           Version: '1.9.5'
           Node ID: '8ff15668-8624-47b5-6e83-7a8bfd715a56'
         Node name: 'b1000.local'
        Datacenter: 'dc1' (Segment: '<all>')
            Server: true (Bootstrap: false)
       Client Addr: [127.0.0.1] (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, gRPC: 8502, DNS: 8600)
      Cluster Addr: 127.0.0.1 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
           Encrypt: Gossip: false, TLS-Outgoing: false, TLS-Incoming: false, Auto-Encrypt-TLS: false

==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:
...
```

In this example, the HTTP API is enabled and listening on port 8500.

#### Test connectivity to HTTP API

If you issue a request to one of the blocked endpoints, the following error will be returned.

```sh
$ curl localhost:8500/v1/status/peers
Endpoint is blocked by agent configuration
```

However, access to other endpoints are still permitted.

```sh
$ curl localhost:8500/v1/agent/members
[
    {
        "Name": "b1000.local",
        "Addr": "127.0.0.1",
        "Port": 8301,
        "Tags": {
            "acls": "0",
            "build": "1.9.5:3c1c2267",
            "dc": "dc1",
            "ft_fs": "1",
            "ft_si": "1",
            "id": "6d157a1b-c893-3903-9037-2e2bd0e6f973",
            "port": "8300",
            "raft_vsn": "3",
            "role": "consul",
            "segment": "",
            "vsn": "2",
            "vsn_max": "3",
            "vsn_min": "2",
            "wan_join_port": "8302"
        },
        "Status": 1,
        "ProtocolMin": 1,
        "ProtocolMax": 5,
        "ProtocolCur": 2,
        "DelegateMin": 2,
        "DelegateMax": 5,
        "DelegateCur": 4
    }
]
```

Comment: The above update in consul config file worked for me in my dev servers. But this blocked all endpoints. I am unable to read any data, write any data or view the members using the different curl commands. Looks like it blocked complete access now. I just need few urls like /coordinate/datacenters, /status/peers, /status/leader, /catalog/datacenters to be blocked

Comment: I've modified my answer to include additional information on blocking access to specific HTTP endpoints without completely disabling the HTTP server.

Comment: The above solution works but what is happening is the end-point "/v1/catalog/datacenters" is blocking the service discovery also. I have two services: service1 and service2. Service2 will discover service1 via consul discovery. When I block the end-points, service2 is not able to discover the service1. The rest of the 3 endpoints is fine. I am looking at an approach where I can control all http endpoint with ACL Token. If we dont provide a token when connecting to any end-point as above it should not allow. Figuring a solution for the same.

Comment: Hi @user3379502, someone opened a thread at https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/blocking-some-http-endpoints-using-consul-acl/26266 with a similar question. Was this you? If so, lets continue the discussion there.

Comment: yes it was me who opened the question in the consul community forum